# autoref on newtheorem

Tags: environments

I want to be able to print the names of my own theorems with autoref.
E.g. on

```
\begin{lemma}
\label{lemma_foo}
  Some lemma
\end{lemma}

\autoref{lemma_foo}
```

I want something like "Lemma 3.2" being printed.

My current approach is:

```
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newcommand{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}

\newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition}
\newcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}
```

Definition shares the counter with lemma, which is intended, however it has the side effect, that referencing definitions results in them being called lemmas.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `cleveref` package does better in these cases.

Comment: I still do have the exact same problem. Setting the \crefname{definition} does nothing, whereas \crefname{lemma} changes it for both lemmas and definitions. I belive this is, because the way I defined "definition" it is treated as a subset of lemma. But I need this for the correct numbering.

Comment: Do you perform the definitions of the `lemma` and `definition` environments before or after loading `hyperref` and `cleveref`?

Comment: \usepackage{cleveref} comes first.

Comment: The `cleveref` package provides labels for environments named `lemma` and `definition`. It shouldn't be necessary to execute `\crefname` directives for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the `lemma` and `definition` environments are defined *after* the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages are loaded, using `\cref` in lieu of `\autoref` should give you what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or 'book'?
\usepackage{ntheorem}  % or 'amsthm'?
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % to emulate \autoref style

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newcommand{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition}
\newcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
\label{lemma_foo}
  Some lemma
\end{lemma}
\autoref{lemma_foo}  (correct) and \cref{lemma_foo} (correct) \dots

\begin{definition}
\label{definition_bar}
  A definition
\end{definition}
\autoref{definition_bar} (incorrect) and \cref{definition_bar} (correct) \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well not exactly, but your working example got me on the right track. It was including \usepackage{ntheorem} that did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @user2089648 - What do you mean by "not exactly"?  Loading `ntheorem` will not make `\autoref` produce the expected output, or will it?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Try commenting it out in the example provided and it will just call everything a lemma.

Comment: @user2089648 - I suppose we're talking about different things. I was focusing on whether `\autoref` can be made to generate the correct output if `ntheorem` is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work with \autoref, but it will only allow the counters to count for each type. So you would have Definition 1.1 then Definition 1.2 and if you add a lemma after that Lemma 1.1. It might be acceptable.

```
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\newcommand{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
\newcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}
```